# Setting size of textbox control inside modal dialog

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Firstly I'm fairly new to the coding scene so please so easy on me. I have an issue where I am putting a text box control inside of a modal dialog window however I cannot seem to get the textbox to resize to take up the full size of the modal window. It just seems to take up half the width of it.

This is how I'm creating my modal window and as you can see I've tried to set the width of the textbox however it doesn't appear to be working:

```
<div id="BusinessRejectModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enter reason for rejection</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessRejectModal" runat="server" Height="300px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="1000px"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My modal classes are set within bootstrap.css which I have a feeling is causing my issue...somewhere

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  min-height: 16.42857143px;
}
.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.modal-footer .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer .btn-group .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-block + .btn-block {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.modal-scrollbar-measure {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  .modal-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .modal-sm {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

I've tried playing around with different width values in the bootstrap.css file however no luck. Can anyone see what I need to do to format this text box properly?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using bootstrap framework, you should take advantage of  `class=form-control` and put `textbox` inside `<div class="form-group"></div>` like as follow

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessRejectModal" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

It will cover the height and width inside `<div class="modalbody">`

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yvxqofsx/)

If you want to increase the height of `textbox` let's say `10 rows` you can achieve it by just adding `rows="10"` inside `textbox`. This way you can increase or decrease the height of `textbox`, no need to define `height / width`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusinessRejectModal" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Rows="10" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

[Example with 10 rows](http://jsfiddle.net/yvxqofsx/1/)

Note: Examples in fiddles are with HTML `textarea` just to give you an idea to take advantage of bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for much for your response. Even after putting in my code in exactly the same way that you had posted it was still only displaying the textbox as a small fraction of what it was supposed to.

I did however manage to sort the issue out. Within my Site.css file I had the following which turned out to be causing my issue

```
    textarea {
max-width: 280px;
text-align: left;
}
```

The 280px was overwriting the width of the text box.

Thanks very much for your response regardless - it was good to see a working example to know that what I had should be working if not for that other setting.

Cheers
Brady